# Google image URL crawl using Nokogiri on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have trouble crawling a site using Nokogiri.

This is my code in my Rails controller:

```
uri = URI("https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=water&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIxs2HlMH4xwIVouWmCh1nigKU&biw=1600&bih=775")
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(Net::HTTP.get(uri))
@kkk = Array.new
@kkk[0] = html_doc.css("a.rg_l")['href']
```

This is Google's first image result 'water':

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.kr/imgres?imgurl=http://www.polyprocessing.com/documents/Water_Save.jpg&amp;imgrefurl=https://u.osu.edu/commoditychainahlqvist/watering/&amp;h=2800&amp;w=4069&amp;tbnid=7a26gIJ0UieGfM:&amp;docid=CxeKK9Q0qRf9HM&amp;ei=rsf3Vdi6HcfimAWBlZbwBQ&amp;tbm=isch&amp;ved=0CBsQMygAMABqFQoTCNjJmJXB-McCFUcxpgodgYoFXg" jsaction="fire.ivg_o;mouseover:str.hmov;mouseout:str.hmou" class="rg_l" style="width: 242px; height: 166px; left: 0px;"><img data-sz="f" name="7a26gIJ0UieGfM:" class="rg_i" alt="water에 대한 이미지 검색결과" jsaction="load:str.tbn" onload="google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" style="width: 242px; height: 166px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px;"><div class="_aOd rg_ilm"><div class="rg_ilmbg"><span class="rg_ilmn"> 4069&nbsp;×&nbsp;2800 - u.osu.edu </span></div></div></a>
```

How can I get `"http://www.polyprocessing.com/documents/Water_Save.jpg"` from it?

I solved it by changing the code like this:

```
uri = URI("https://www.google.co.kr/search?q="+@one_post.wmk+"&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIxs2HlMH4xwIVouWmCh1nigKU&biw=1600&bih=775")
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(Net::HTTP.get(uri))
@kkk = Array.new
@kkk = html_doc.css("a > img")[0].attr('src')
```

I read http://www.sitepoint.com/nokogiri-fundamentals-extract-html-web/

Comment: follow the link and save the 301 from it ?

Comment: I dont know what is 301...  but i solve it anyway thank yoU!

Comment: 301 is the http status code for a redirect. so maybe post the answer how you solved it

Comment: `html_doc.css("a > img")[0].attr('src')` can be better written as
`html_doc.at("a > img")['src']` Also, the use of `@kkk` has code smell hinting that you're not familiar with how variable scoping works.